# How can you create a command to run other applications in Windows Batch?

Tags: html, batch-file, vbscript

My goal is to run other programs through the command of one in Windows Batch. [Here are the files I would like to run through a single command if possible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdkDW.png)

However the code that I have attempted at best is this

```
start "C:\users\excre\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding Files\GTA Chinatown\Terms & Conditions.html" 
start "C:\users\excre\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding Files\GTA Chinatown\Audio_Synthesis-Program.vbs"
start "C:\users\excre\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding Files\GTA Chinatown\test3.bat"
```

[This resulted in a simple location CMD tab as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUcks.png)

---

If anyone has a potential solution to this please mention below

Comment: do you want to run these in parallel or queue?

Comment: the first quoted argument of [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) is set as a title (as you can see in your screenshot).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `&&` if you wanna run the commands in a single terminal using a queue.

```
command1.bat && command2.bat && command3.bat && test.html
```

if you use `start` before any commands here it opens on a new window.

```
start "Mytitle" test.html  && command1.bat && command2.bat && command3.bat
```

update:

```
start "Mytitle" "C:\users\excre\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding Files\GTA Chinatown\Terms & Conditions.html" &&
"C:\users\excre\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding Files\GTA Chinatown\Audio_Synthesis-Program.vbs"
&&
"C:\users\excre\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding Files\GTA Chinatown\test3.bat"
```

i think this is what you look for.

---

if you want to keep open your main command window you can add `PAUSE` to the queue.

```
start "Mytitle" test.html && command1.bat && command2.bat && command3.bat && PAUSE
```

Comment: When I run that it begins to open the files in a new tab but closes automatically? Is this a possible error with my programs? Thank you for the answer as well.

Comment: `start` considers the first set of quotes that it encounters to be the title of the window

Comment: @Streak I didn't understand exactly what are you asking but if you want to keep open the window add `PAUSE` to your queue